Conda confige proxy_servers failed
When I using minoconda to create a new env there is an error saying the ProxyError. I have configured both the system proxy and .condarc file. I'm confused. In our team, the server is behind a proxy so that can access Internet.
The error as follow:
...
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1000)')': /anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json.zst

failed

ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration.
Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory,
any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy
configuration settings.

The server OS is Centos7.6.
The system profile in /etc/profile:
export http_proxy=http://[MY_PROXY_IP]:9999
export https_proxy=https://[MY_PROXY_IP]:9999
export no_proxy="localhost, 127.0.0.1, ::1, 10.*.*.*, 192.168.*.*, 172.*.*.*"

The .condarc config:
proxy_servers:  
  http: http://[MY_PROXY_IP]:9999
  https: https://[MY_PROXY_IP]:9999
ssl_verify: false

I have checked the system proxy is correct. I can run curl https://www.baidu.com.
And I can also run pip to install like: pip install numpy --porxy=http://192.168.101.19:9999 which mean the system proxy is correct?
I read from anaconda doc about proxy part, it is still not helpful.

Try again with -vv flags to catch the verbose error output.
